# Assigning an int name to select a word from a string array

Tags: java, arrays

Here's a class i made to create random names but one line keeps getting an error (not a main class)

```
public class nameGenerator {

String [] namesFirst= {"Micheal","Stewart","Robbinson","Tang"};
String [] namesMiddle= {"Jordan","James","Stanly","Choo" };
String [] namesLast= {"IV","Lee","Persson"};


int a = namesFirst.length;
int b = namesMiddle.length;
int c = namesLast.length;


int x = (int) (Math.random()* a);
int y = (int) (Math.random()* b);   
int z = (int) (Math.random()* c);



System.out.println(namesFirst[x] + namesMiddle[y] + namesLast[z]);
//the error is here /\



}
```

Comment: System.out.println(namesFirst[x] + namesMiddle[y] + namesLast[z]);

Comment: @user2277371, We're looking for the stacktrace.

Comment: WHAT is the error? Not WHERE.

Comment: I mean, the error log, what does Eclipse or whatever say about this? Or what is the result in this code, and what were you expecting?

Comment: the entire thing was underlined but i fixed it already

Answer (score 4):

ohh use method here. you can't use `System.out.println()` out side the method.

```
System.out.println(namesFirst[x] + namesMiddle[y] + namesLast[z]); 
// put inside a method
```

You have to change your code as follows

```
public class nameGenerator { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] namesFirst= {"Micheal","Stewart","Robbinson","Tang"};
    String [] namesMiddle= {"Jordan","James","Stanly","Choo" };
    String [] namesLast= {"IV","Lee","Persson"};

    int a = namesFirst.length;
    int b = namesMiddle.length;
    int c = namesLast.length;
    int x = (int) (Math.random()* a);
    int y = (int) (Math.random()* b);
    int z = (int) (Math.random()* c);

    System.out.println(namesFirst[x] + namesMiddle[y] + namesLast[z]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main method is in another class, put your code above in a method then call on the method from your main class and it should work.